# FFmpeg : How to create rotating 3D (haas) effect in mp3 using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, soundeffect

I want to add a rotating 3d effect (Haas effect) in mp3. I mean that the audio will seem to change its directions from left to right and vice versa periodically (as shown below) when listened through the headphone. For this, I searched on the Internet and tried to achieve it in the following ways:

1. Firstly, I thought, if I change the audio of the left and right channel periodically (like when the right channel has full volume (100%), left channel has low volume (20%) and vice versa) then I can achieve it, but it's not like 3D.
2. Secondly, when I researched more than found that it is done by creating a delay between the two channels. I found that I can create a delay of 0.0 to 0.8 milliseconds according to requirement.
   To do this, I use the following commands in FFmpeg :

Step 1: Splitting Audio Channels :

```
ffmpeg -i D:\ffmpeg\Down.mp3 -map_channel 0.0.0 D:\ffmpeg\L.mp3 -map_channel 0.0.1 D:\ffmpeg\R.mp3
```

Stem 2: Splitting Left channel into parts :

> Note: We will only change the speed of Left channel so we split left
> channel into 4 seconds parts.

```
ffmpeg -i D:\ffmpeg\L.mp3 -f segment -segment_time 4 D:\ffmpeg\Split\%03d.mp3
```

Step 3: Changing the tempo of each part

> Now We change the tempo (speed) of each part so it may feel like the sound
> is moving from left to right and vice versa

```
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\000.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\000.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\001.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\001.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\002.mp3 -af atempo=0.9992 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\002.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\003.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\003.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\004.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\004.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\005.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\005.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\006.mp3 -af atempo=0.9992 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\006.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\007.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\007.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\008.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\008.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\009.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\009.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\010.mp3 -af atempo=0.9992 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\010.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\011.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\011.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\012.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\012.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\013.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\013.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\014.mp3 -af atempo=0.9992 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\014.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\015.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\015.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\016.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\016.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\017.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\017.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\018.mp3 -af atempo=0.9992 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\018.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\019.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\019.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\020.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\020.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\021.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\021.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\022.mp3 -af atempo=0.9992 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\022.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\023.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\023.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\024.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\024.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\025.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\025.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\026.mp3 -af atempo=0.9992 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\026.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\027.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\027.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\028.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\028.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\029.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\029.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\030.mp3 -af atempo=0.9992 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\030.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\031.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\031.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\032.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\032.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\033.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\033.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\034.mp3 -af atempo=0.9992 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\034.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\035.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\035.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\036.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\036.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\037.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\037.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\038.mp3 -af atempo=0.9992 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\038.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\039.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\039.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\040.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\040.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\041.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\041.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\042.mp3 -af atempo=0.9992 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\042.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\043.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\043.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\044.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\044.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\045.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\045.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\046.mp3 -af atempo=0.9992 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\046.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\047.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\047.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\048.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\048.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\049.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\049.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\050.mp3 -af atempo=0.9992 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\050.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\051.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\051.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\052.mp3 -af atempo=1.0008 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\052.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\053.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\053.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i D:\ffmpeg\Split\054.mp3 -af atempo=1.0000 D:\ffmpeg\Modi\054.mp3
```

> Here I used 1.0000 for normal speed
> and 1.0008 for increased speed
> and 0.9992 for decreased speed

Spet 4: Merging small pieces of audio

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i D:\ffmpeg\f.txt -c copy D:\ffmpeg\output.mp3
```

where f.txt contains :

```
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\000.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\001.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\002.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\003.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\004.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\005.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\006.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\007.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\008.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\009.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\010.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\011.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\012.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\013.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\014.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\015.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\016.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\017.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\018.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\019.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\020.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\021.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\022.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\023.mp3'
file 'D:\ffmpeg\Modi\024.mp3'
```

Step 5: The last operation is combining the both channels :

```
ffmpeg -i D:\ffmpeg\L.mp3 -i D:\ffmpeg\output.mp3 -filter_complex [0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout] -map [aout] D:\ffmpeg\LRM.mp3
```

But even then the result is very poor. It looks like FFmpeg combines audio in Step 4 took a delay after each audio.

I think there may be some bug in my solution. I don't think that I can change tempo like this in audio without splitting the audio(Let me know if I am wrong).

Does anyone have a different solution to achieve this?
Please help me in this. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want the [apulsator](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#apulsator) filter or the eponymous [Haas](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#haas) filter.

```
ffmpeg -i D:\ffmpeg\Down.mp3 -af apulsator=hz=0.125 out.mp3
```

This will rotate the audio from left to right and back in 8 seconds (`1/0.125`).

Comment: Thank you Sir, It works for fantastically. But I have a confusion that if apulsator can do this than what haas filter do?Does they produce same results? If not then what is the difference? Can you please give a haas filter example also? I had also tried to use it but not able to use because it does not have an example. It's here "https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-haas"

Comment: haas does not perform rotation. It provides directionality for a mono signal.

Comment: Thanks again. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

i has the same request and topicstarter inspired me to step he's way. I guess add acrossfade is that iterations needed. ffmpeg even to segment have asegment filter. I think will be smart use ffmpeg lib for python as easy way to passthrough iterations.

UPD:

i was kind make it with pydup library.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
def Haas(stereo, action: int, period = 2):
    def iterate(flip,input,ch):
        output=AudioSegment.empty().set_channels(input[ch].channels).set_frame_rate(input[ch].frame_rate).set_sample_width(input[ch].sample_width)
        for i in range(framecount//segment):
            flip=flip*(1-(i%2)*2)
            slice=input[ch].get_sample_slice((0+i)*segment, (1+i)*segment-1).set_frame_rate(-1*flip*action+framerate)
            slice.frame_rate=framerate    
            output+=slice
        #at least 1 sample is forsaken
        if (framecount//segment)%2==0:
            output+=input[ch].get_sample_slice(0+(framecount//segment)*segment, framecount)
            print(ch, 'channel got not silence')
        else:
            if framecount%segment==0:
                append=AudioSegment.silent(duration=segment-1, frame_rate=1000)
            else:
                flip=-flip
                append=AudioSegment.silent(duration=framecount%segment-1, frame_rate=1000)
            append.frame_rate=framerate
            print(ch, 'channel got silence')
            input[ch]+=append
            slice=input[ch].get_sample_slice((0+framecount//segment)*segment, (1+framecount//segment)*segment-1).set_frame_rate(-1*flip*action+framerate)
            slice.frame_rate=framerate
            output+=slice
        return output
            
    input=stereo.split_to_mono()
    framecount=int(input[0].frame_count())
    framerate=int(input[0].frame_rate)
    segment=int(framerate*period*0.5)
    action=int(-action*framerate/segment*0.5)
    if framecount<framerate:
        append=AudioSegment.silent(duration=framerate-framecount, frame_rate=1000)
        append.framerate=framerate
        input[0]+=append
        input[1]+=append
        print('input got silence',framerate-framecount)
        print('input got length',input[0].frame_count())
        framecount=int(input[0].frame_count())
    left=iterate(1,input,0)
    right=iterate(-1,input,1)
    print('right is',right.frame_count())
    print('left is',left.frame_count())
    if right.frame_count()!=left.frame_count():
        framecountR=right.frame_count()
        framecountL=left.frame_count()
        if framecountR>framecountL:
            append=AudioSegment.silent(duration=framecountR-framecountL, frame_rate=1000)
            append.frame_rate=framerate
            left+=append
        else:
            append=AudioSegment.silent(duration=framecountL-framecountR, frame_rate=1000)
            append.frame_rate=framerate
            right+=append  
    return AudioSegment.from_mono_audiosegments(left,right)
```

i was'nt be sitted to throughly test it.
UPD: by using pydup i face that output file still occupied by python so i just add close() method and it solve that.

```
output.export(out_f="W://Bass+Chord.wav", format="wav")
open("W://Bass+Chord.wav").close()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, a place that clear answers are also welcome, without generic information